# How do I find out the feature names used to develop a model using sklearn GridSearch?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, grid-search

Say for example, I trained a model using sklearn grid-search as follows:

```py
model = GridSearchCV(xgb_model,optimization_dict, cv=5,
                        scoring='roc_auc', verbose=10, n_jobs=-1)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```py
print(type(model))

[OUTPUT]: sklearn.model_selection._search.GridSearchCV
```

How do I get the list of feature names used to develop the model?

Comment: Usually the model use the columns of the X_train data, but if you are looking for feature selection with xgboost, you can retrieve it from the trainned model. Heres a link that might help you with that: https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-importance-and-feature-selection-with-xgboost-in-python/

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I guess I need to clarify the question. Imagine, I give this model object to someone else to load, and they have no idea what the feature names used to develop this model are. In such a case, can I findout the features names?

Comment: I believe not, but a simple hack would be to add manually an attribute in the model. like  `model.feature_names = list(X_train.columns)`, something like that

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code:

> `model.best_params_`

and see this example output:

> {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}